# How to Scale images to imageview perfectly with fixed width and height without distorting the image in Android

Tags: android, image

Iam creating an app to access images from gallery or camera. For this i have an imageview with 280/280dp dimension. How to Scale images from camera/gallery(which are bigger images) to below imageview perfectly having fixed width and height without distorting the image in Android:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:id="@+id/mainImage"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_settings_main_image"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/container_toolbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />
```

---

activity_main.xml(Full Layout)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="in.ABC.activity.ProfileSettings"
android:background="#93BFB6">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />



</LinearLayout>


<TextView android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_settings_name"
    android:id="@+id/nameView"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainImage"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mainImage"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mainImage"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:id="@+id/mainImage"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_settings_main_image"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/container_toolbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/editName"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_settings_image"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/nameView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nameView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nameView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nameView" />

    <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/editImage"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_settings_image_2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mainImage"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mainImage"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/mainImage"
    android:focusable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the image's scale factor doesn't match the `ImageView`'s scale factor, then you cannot match the height/width without sacrificing the clarity. You'll have to compromise and decide if you want to have some of the image cut off, or have the entire image fit inside but acknowledge that there will be some left over space.

See here for more information regarding `android:scaleType` http://www.techrepublic.com/article/clear-up-ambiguity-about-android-image-view-scale-types-with-this-guide/

Answer (score 0):

You can try Android ImageView.ScaleType:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:id="@+id/mainImage"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_settings_main_image"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/container_toolbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />
```

Result of the code:

[Result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY4N8.png)

The original image:

[Original Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4FIG.jpg)

Comment: My images get stretched to fill the additional gaps in the imageview when i use  android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: Did you try android:scaleType="CENTER_INSIDE"? Also please read [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)